# Angular 6 run time Error: StaticInjectorError(a)[n -> n]

Tags: angular6

When I tried to build my Angular 6 app using ng build --prod --aot, It reduced the size of the chunks but giving error on console and not starting.

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: StaticInjectorError(a)[n -> n]:
```

StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[n -> n]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for n!
Error: StaticInjectorError(a)[n -> n]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[n -> n]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for n!
    at n.get (main.94192bc69c04bfd4026a.js:1)
    at main.94192bc69c04bfd4026a.js:1
    at n (main.94192bc69c04bfd4026a.js:1)
    at n.get (main.94192bc69c04bfd4026a.js:1)
    at main.94192bc69c04bfd4026a.js:1
    at n (main.94192bc69c04bfd4026a.js:1)
    at n.get (main.94192bc69c04bfd4026a.js:1)
    at Ao (main.94192bc69c04bfd4026a.js:1)
    at main.94192bc69c04bfd4026a.js:1
    at Eo (main.94192bc69c04bfd4026a.js:1)
    at n.get (main.94192bc69c04bfd4026a.js:1)
    at main.94192bc69c04bfd4026a.js:1
    at n (main.94192bc69c04bfd4026a.js:1)
    at n.get (main.94192bc69c04bfd4026a.js:1)
    at main.94192bc69c04bfd4026a.js:1
    at n (main.94192bc69c04bfd4026a.js:1)
    at n.get (main.94192bc69c04bfd4026a.js:1)
    at Ao (main.94192bc69c04bfd4026a.js:1)
    at main.94192bc69c04bfd4026a.js:1
    at Eo (main.94192bc69c04bfd4026a.js:1)
    at P (polyfills.b63b1ec9df8730de69cb.js:1)
    at P (polyfills.b63b1ec9df8730de69cb.js:1)
    at polyfills.b63b1ec9df8730de69cb.js:1
    at t.invokeTask (polyfills.b63b1ec9df8730de69cb.js:1)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (main.94192bc69c04bfd4026a.js:1)
    at t.invokeTask (polyfills.b63b1ec9df8730de69cb.js:1)
    at e.runTask (polyfills.b63b1ec9df8730de69cb.js:1)
    at d (polyfills.b63b1ec9df8730de69cb.js:1)
    at 
Gn @ main.94192bc69c04bfd4026a.js:1